# What is faster - a matrix, raster or a dataframe?

Tags: raster, r, data-frame

I have rasters over which I am performing mathematical operations. For example, where I need to calculate flow distance or distance between two grid points.

What format is generally considered faster for such operations?

Should I work directly on the raster format, instead?

I also converted the data to matrix and dataframe

as.matrix and as.data.frame

The raster has entirely numeric values.
Not sure which is faster. I am new to raster package in R, and I have mostly only worked in dataframes.

Comment: It depends, I don't think it's possible to answer this question as it stands. This really needs more detail, and especially a working example.  Also things keep changing, where it was slow to use data.frame now it's much better with dplyr::data_frame - but this is just one possible nuance among many.

Comment: Personally, I prefer matrices over 'Raster*' objects when performing mathematical operations due to the easy connectivity with `*apply`, parallel processing and **Rcpp**. However, as raster layers grow bigger, so do matrices - i.e., running `as.matrix` on really large 'Raster*' objects will cause R to run out of memory sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

"Faster" is relative. Faster to upload? Faster to access and run calculations? Because so many variables exist between systems and data, the best way to get a guaranteed answer for your processes and data is to run it using each of the three formats.

A similar Stack Exchange Answer can be found here: [Data frame or matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158790/data-frame-or-matrix)

> The answer depends on what you are going to do with the data in
>   data.frame/matrix. If it is going to be passed to other functions then
>   the expected type of the arguments of these functions determine the
>   choice.